# How to hide header when scrolling inside Intel XDK?

Tags: html, intel-xdk

I'm trying to hide the header when scrolling down and show it again when scrolling up in mobile. Anyone know how this can be done in Intel XDK app framework 2.x using html + cordova? 
I know there is examples like this https://medium.com/@mariusc23/hide-header-on-scroll-down-show-on-scroll-up-67bbaae9a78c but it wont work inside intel xdk for me.

Question, has anyone been able to accomplish this inside the intel xdk + cordova framework, in that case how? Any help or input highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works fine for me, both in the Emulator and in the Debug tab on a usb connected Android device, but I had to include jquery explicitly.  I basically copied the code from the link you provided and it worked.  If you're using AppFramework, there might be a possible priority issue in the CSS rules, which you should be able to fix by making the scrolling related rules more specific (class scroll or specific ids if necessary). There also could be a conflict between AppFramework and jQuery, but I'd have to see more details to address that queston.

It looks like AppFramework does interfere with header and footer, so you could also try using divs with custom classes or names in place of header and footer elements.

I did have a few bugs, which I tracked down using the Debug tab and the emulator's debugger.  The thing to look for is to make sure the class on the header element changes when you scroll up and down.  If that is working, then you can check the CSS rules and see if maybe something is taking priority.

Comment: Okay thanks going to try it out again later, if you're not using app framework, which one do you use?

Comment: I just used jQuery and straight HTML code, no other frameworks or libs.